# Converting int division to float (f)

Tags: c#, floating-point, media-player

I'm using MediaPlayer for playing sound, to change the volume you do have to set the value of a Volume property which is a float. (Example shows 0.5f as setting).

My settings for volume are percent based, how would I convert my say 80% volume to 0.5f to set the volume with. My code:

```
float volume = (Program.EffectsVolumeSlider.Percent > 0 ? Convert.ToSingle(Program.EffectsVolumeSlider.Percent / 100) : 0.0f);

this.FireballSound.Volume = volume;
this.IceSound.Volume = volume;
this.SmokeSound.Volume = volume;
```

This outputs the volume as 0.0 when the `Program.EffectsVolumeSlider.Percent` is 55?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code uses integer division:

```
55 / 100
```

Will *always* return 0, because the integer piece of that division is 0. You need to cast one or more of the operands to float, the easiest way would be to do:

```
Program.EffectsVolumeSlider.Percent / 100.0f
```

This forces floating point division, which will return the correct value (.55)

Comment: +1. Note that this may be only half of answer - missing linear interpolation for "say 80% volume to 0.5f", but sample in the post could simply be wrong (definitely missing what range 0-100% maps to like `[0,0.79f]`).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, yeah, I wasn't sure exactly what the OP wanted for that interpolation so I left it off. Thanks for noting it though!

Comment: `Convert.ToSingle` is actually useless in this case.

Comment: @Wallstrider I suspected as much, but left in to closer match the original code and in case there was some obscure reason for it. Thinking about it again, I agree it could cause some confusion, so I removed it. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

```
float EffectsVolumeSliderPercent = 55.0f;
float volume = EffectsVolumeSliderPercent > 0.0f ? EffectsVolumeSliderPercent / 100.0f : 0.0f;
Console.WriteLine(volume);
Console.ReadLine();
```

[image: result]